# Detect data types will improve import times

Tags: powerbi, etl

Hi I have came across a question in power bi. The question is stating that when we are importing a CSV setting the data type detection to based on first 200 rows will improve import times? It this statement true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have found the answer it will not improve the loading time. No specific documentation but i have tried it myself and understood.